# Wisely burninating tags

Tags: discussion, tags

What **exactly** does a tag need to be up for burnination ?
I feel kind of trapped every time I make those requests because of of this problem :

- Not enough good question with the tag so let's just edit and let the tag delete itself
- Too many question asked with that tag so burninating might cause a lot of mistagged questions

When is a tag ready to go away ?

Answer (score 2):

The question shouldn't be "When is a tag ready to go away?", but "What do we have to do to burninate it?".

If it's not on enough questions, then edit them all and solve the problem yourself.

If it's on a lot of questions, then bring it to Meta and get help.